# Design dropdown with symbols Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Would like to design a dropdown in Excel which gives symbols as options instead of a list of values.  I'm well-acquainted with VBA and Excel, so I can develop it if I have a starting point.  Does someone have a snippet of something similar.

Comment: What symbols are we talking about? And why not just make a list of symbols the way you would make a normal list with buildin function? Isnt that easier?

Comment: As an example, use (msoShapeFlowchartSummingJunction, 270.75, 101.25, _
        48.24, 48.24) After I get the basic code, I will manipulate the color/size/properties.   is there a way to assign this to a cell, then make a list of various symbols?

Comment: Oke, so you are refering to shapes rather than symbols. Shapes cannot be directly put into a dropdown list as it isn't an actual cell value. What you could do however is create a list and tie pictures/shapes to it. [Here](https://www.excel-bytes.com/photos-tied-to-dropdown-list-selection-in-excel/) is a tutorial.

Comment: In a user form, or on a worksheet?  How large a list, and what kind of symbols - where would they come from and how large?  Just symbols or also text?

Comment: I would like the dropdown on a user form, and the output to be shown on a different form.  The symbols are just icons from the shapes menu, shrunk to the size of 12-14 font, with adjusted weight and color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have control over all of the computers on which the excel file will be used, a potentially simple workaround is to install a font containing the symbols you want to use, then select that font for the dropdown object. For example: https://www.wfonts.com/font/flowchart

[image]

If you need more control over the shapes, then you can create your own font based on .svg files (that you find or create) using: https://icomoon.io/app/#/select

Unfortunately this solution doesn't allow for different color selections in the same list. If the color depends on the shape, some VBA could change the font color after the selection is made. If each shape can have multiple colors, then a 2nd color picker object would be required, such as a button that invokes Application.Dialogs(xlDialogEditColor).